# Can I send ics file to outlook attendee which updates the attendees status to accepted/declined

Tags: c#

I am implementing an automated calendar event meeting processor that processes a meeting request from an Organizer. I then send out a email (with mime) attachment to approve/decline the meeting request. This updates me (as attendee) as accepted/declined on the Organizer's calendar BUT how do I actually update my (as attendee) status to accepted/declined on my calendar.

Here is the ics I send to the organizer which works perfectly. I have tried sending the same ics to myself in hopes that my status is updated according to my reply but to no avail. Please help.

```
var str = new StringBuilder();
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
str.AppendLine($"METHOD:REPLY");
str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//iCal Integration");
str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine($"UID:{uid}");
str.AppendLine($"DTSTAMP:{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}");
str.AppendLine($"ORGANIZER:mailto:{organizer}");
str.AppendLine($"ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT={EventParticipationStatus.Accepted}:mailto:{room}");
str.AppendLine($"DTSTART:{start:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}");
str.AppendLine($"DTEND:{end:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}");
str.AppendLine($"LOCATION:{location}");
str.AppendLine($"DESCRIPTION:{description}");
str.AppendLine($"SUMMARY:{summary}");
str.AppendLine($"STATUS:{EventStatus.Confirmed}");
str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
```

What I would want to happen is that the attendee's calendar also reflects that it has accepted/declined the meeting